# What is wrong with my code? undefined method `each' for "1":String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, schema, categories

Hi so I am creating a recipe submission app. On the submit page I have a drop down list to pick the category they want the recipe to be under. When I hit submit I get the error in my Recipes controller:

```
undefined method `each' for "1":String
```

highlighted error:

```
def create


     @recipe = Recipe.new(recipe_params)
```

What is going on here?

My drop down for categories:

```
 <%= f.collection_select :categories, Category.all, :id, :name, :prompt => "Select a category" %>
```

Categories model:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :recipes
end
```

Recipe model:

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
   validates :description, :nickname, :title, :ingredients, :instructions, :categories, presence: true

   has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end
```

Seeds: (I assign an id to each category, so "1" is the ID I selected in the dropdown.)

```
Category.delete_all 

Category.create(:name => "Vegan",
  :id => 1)
Category.create(:name => "Low Carb",
  :id => 2)
Category.create(:name => "Ketogenic",
  :id => 3)
Category.create(:name => "Paleo",
  :id => 4)
Category.create(:name => "Flour-free",
  :id => 5)
Category.create(:name => "Misc",
  :id => 6)
```

categories table:

```
class CreateCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :categories, :primary_key => :id  do |t|
   t.string :name
      t.timestamps null: false
    end

  end

  change_column :categories, :id, :string


end
```

Categories controller:

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController

  class CategoriesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @categories = Category.all
    end
  end

  def show
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    end
  end


  def new
    @category = Category.new
    end
  end

  def edit
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
  end


  def create
    @category = Category.new(params[:category])
  end


  def update
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @category.update_attributes(params[:category])
        format.html { redirect_to @category, notice: 'Category was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @category.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    @category.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to categories_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end

end
```

Is anybody able to figure out the issue? I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you!!!!

edit:

recipe controller:

```
class RecipesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @recipes = Recipe.all
  end

  def show
    @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @recipe = Recipe.new
  end

  def edit
    @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @recipe = Recipe.new(recipe_params)

    if @recipe.save
      redirect_to recipes_url
    else
      render:new
  end
end

def update
    @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])

    if @recipe.update_attributes(recipe_params)
      redirect_to recipe_path(@recipe)
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
    @recipe.destroy
    redirect_to recipes_path
  end

  private
  def recipe_params
    params.require(:recipe).permit(:nickname, :website, :instagram, :title, :description, :instructions, :ingredients, :notes, :embed, :photo, :categories)
  end

end
```

error log:

```
undefined method `each' for "1":String

Extracted source (around line #19):
17
18
19
20
21
22


  def create
    @recipe = Recipe.new(recipe_params)

    if @recipe.save
      redirect_to recipes_url

Rails.root: /Users/ashleighalmeida/mixi

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/recipes_controller.rb:19:in `create'
Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"l01VMCMWBhW4MuWINPqolGwqrM5AIJScw/4+FjupVMLRWKX0okdVYCSME+BJD97XjklWYLhKdflBTRPcucXm3w==",
 "recipe"=>{"nickname"=>"sf",
 "website"=>"sdfs",
 "instagram"=>"sdfs",
 "title"=>"sdfs",
 "description"=>"sdfs",
 "ingredients"=>"sdfs",
 "instructions"=>"sdfs",
 "notes"=>"sdfs",
 "embed"=>"sdfs",
 "photo"=>"sfds",
 "categories"=>"1"},
 "commit"=>"Create Recipe"}
```

Comment: paste the complete error log

Comment: With dropdown you can only select one category so does it make sense for `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship? Also, an error probably occurs in `RecipesController`, we are gonna need it.

Comment: Why are you changing a primary key field to a string?

Comment: What does `recipe_params` look like?

Comment: @lurker params.require(:recipe).permit(:nickname, :website, :instagram, :title, :description, :instructions, :ingredients, :notes, :embed, :photo, :categories)

Comment: @SrdjanPejic it wouldn't let me add :id manually to the table, so I had to find a workaround on here

Comment: @katafrakt okay im going to edit the original post with log and recipes controller, one sec, thanks!

Comment: @icecreamrabbit you shouldn't be adding an ID manually ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your migration file should look like:

```
class CreateCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :categories do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Because `id` is the primary key rails takes default, No need to specify externally

And also modify the `strong params`

**UPDATE**

```
def recipe_params
  params.require(:recipe).permit(:nickname, :website, :instagram, :title, :description, :instructions, :ingredients, :notes, :embed, :photo, categories_attributes: [:id, :name])
end
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your time. I made the changes. You are the best! except now I get this error when I hit submit: 1 error prohibited this recipe from being saved:

Categories can't be blank .. why is it saying its blank if i selected it from dropdown?

Comment: @icecreamrabbit updated the post, please take a look, thanks

Comment: thanks for your time again. i made the changes and now i get: http://i60.tinypic.com/3340psl.png  :( sigh  i don't know where 'each' is coming from

Answer (score 0):

`collection_select` is not suitable for *_many relationships and you have one in your `Recipe` model. Either change it into one-to-many relationship ot use better input for this, for example:

```
 <%= f.collection_check_boxes :category_ids, Category.all, :id, :name %>
```

Note `category_ids` instead of `categories` and adjust your `recipe_params` method accordingly.